# How execute all requests sequentially instead of parallel in ASP.NET WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I am using WebApi 2 to implement REST service, as per by observations WebApi 2 executes all request parallel, But I want to execute all request sequentially.

Please someone can help to execute all requests sequentially instead of parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API/REST services is stateless. So it has nothing to do with sequential or parallel execution. If you can describe/explain the problem you are trying to solve, then we can discuss.

Comment: I have added my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525543/how-to-manage-cache-in-asp-net-webapi2) with detail description. Please can you help me for this.